# Square Connect adjust inventory quantity to fixed

Tags: inventory-management, square-connect

how i could adjust the quantity on square connect API as fixed type, for example:

```
on Square : 10 items
And on My System: 5 items
```

i want to update the quantity on square to 5 , and yes, i don't know what the quantity on square so i cant use -5 and adjustment type SALE.
is there any option for Inventory Adjustment Type to make it FIXED.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to set a variation's inventory quantity to an absolute amount. You can perform the following steps as a workaround:

1. Use the [List Inventory](http://docs.connect.squareup.com/#get-inventory) endpoint to identify a particular variation's current quantity.
2. Use the [Adjust Inventory](http://docs.connect.squareup.com/#post-inventory_variationid) endpoint to adjust the variation's quantity by the amount necessary to match your external system. You can set the `adjustment_type` parameter in your request to `MANUAL_ADJUST` to indicate that the adjustment is not related to a sale or increase in stock.

I've submitted a feature request to the API engineering team.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i already thought about this steps, but the problem that we have more than 1000 item, and also, there is no way to get a specific item quantity, and one more thing which i am trying to figure out, if we have 1 item in stock, and our customer wanted to buy 2 from Square Register POS for ipad, as i understand, it will still go through the sale and then we will have 1 over-sale, that's so important to be fixed, thanks